# Rails App "Permission Denied" error when installing refinerycms

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, refinerycms

While trying to install refinery, a rails app, I keep getting the following error:

```
ESL@new-host-2 ~$ refinerycms /Application/MAMP/htdocs/goodwatching
      create  
/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/1.9.1/fileutils.rb:247:in `mkdir': Permission denied - /Application (Errno::EACCES)
    from /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/1.9.1/fileutils.rb:247:in `fu_mkdir'
    from /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/1.9.1/fileutils.rb:221:in `block (2 levels) in mkdir_p'
    from /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/1.9.1/fileutils.rb:219:in `reverse_each'
    from /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/1.9.1/fileutils.rb:219:in `block in mkdir_p'
    from /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/1.9.1/fileutils.rb:205:in `each'
    from /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/1.9.1/fileutils.rb:205:in `mkdir_p'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/thor-0.16.0/lib/thor/actions/empty_directory.rb:51:in `block in invoke!'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/thor-0.16.0/lib/thor/actions/empty_directory.rb:133:in `call'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/thor-0.16.0/lib/thor/actions/empty_directory.rb:133:in `invoke_with_conflict_check'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/thor-0.16.0/lib/thor/actions/empty_directory.rb:50:in `invoke!'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/thor-0.16.0/lib/thor/actions.rb:95:in `action'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/thor-0.16.0/lib/thor/actions/empty_directory.rb:15:in `empty_directory'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/generators/app_base.rb:103:in `create_root'
    from (eval):1:in `create_root'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/thor-0.16.0/lib/thor/task.rb:27:in `run'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/thor-0.16.0/lib/thor/invocation.rb:120:in `invoke_task'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/thor-0.16.0/lib/thor/invocation.rb:126:in `block in invoke_all'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/thor-0.16.0/lib/thor/invocation.rb:126:in `each'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/thor-0.16.0/lib/thor/invocation.rb:126:in `map'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/thor-0.16.0/lib/thor/invocation.rb:126:in `invoke_all'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/thor-0.16.0/lib/thor/group.rb:238:in `dispatch'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/thor-0.16.0/lib/thor/base.rb:425:in `start'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/refinerycms-2.0.10/bin/refinerycms:30:in `<top (required)>'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/bin/refinerycms:23:in `load'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/bin/refinerycms:23:in `<main>'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/bin/ruby_noexec_wrapper:14:in `eval'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/bin/ruby_noexec_wrapper:14:in `<main>'
```

I've seen a couple similar questions but the resolution always seems to be that target directory either doesn't exist or is owned by root. I've checked and my directory exists, is owned by me and has permissions 755.

**update**

I tried a lot of things so I'm not 100% sure this is relevant, but I updated rvm and then I was able to run `refinercyms goodwatching` from inside the original /goodwatching directory. But now I'm getting this multiple times when I run it:

```
NoMethodError: private method `open' called for Gem::Package:Class
An error occured while installing rake (10.0.4), and Bundler cannot continue.
Make sure that `gem install rake -v '10.0.4'` succeeds before bundling.
```

When I run `gem install rake -v '10.0.4'` it does succede, but then I get the same error again immediately after.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to use sudo

```
sudo refinerycms /Application/MAMP/htdocs/goodwatching
```

**UPDATE**

try to remove Gemfile.lock

then

```
sudo gem update --system
sudo gem install bundler
sudo bundle install
```

Comment: I tried that and it didn't work. But I did make some progress (see my update above).

Comment: Did you try to run "mkdir /Application/MAMP/htdocs/goodwatching/test" ? What is the output ?

Comment: I see `/goowatching/Gemfile` is that it?

Comment: @Emerson nope it's the .lock one. Run 'ls -lh' from your application root path

Comment: It's not there. Should it be?

Comment: @Emerson Probably :) In all my rails projects I got this file. You can try bundle update

Comment: @Emerson the best way is to lauch gem update --system then gem install bundler

Comment: with the option '--system' ?

Comment: Oops. I spoke to soon. `bundle update` ended with this: `Errno::EACCES: Permission denied - /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/build_info/multi_json-1.7.2.info
An error occurred while installing multi_json (1.7.2), and Bundler cannot
continue.
Make sure that `gem install multi_json -v '1.7.2'` succeeds before bundling.
`