# Why can't I start my webserver (`rails server`)?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I've created a new rails app using rails composer (https://github.com/RailsApps/rails-composer). however when I start my rails server (WEBrick), I get the following error:

```
~/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p448/lib/ruby/1.9.1/fileutils.rb:247:in `mkdir': Permission denied
```

I've looked at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16370786/rails-app-permission-denied-error-when-installing-refinerycms) and tried the steps in the selected answer but I'm getting the same issue. This seems like a conflict between RVM and Bundler since I've got ruby-1.9.3 as the top level directory and 1.9.1 as an intermediate directory. Not *really* sure what that means.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is generally the result of some directory in your Rails directory not having the correct permissions.

Here is an in-depth discussion of the permissions in Rails: https://stackoverflow.com/a/6091058/1669208

If you wanted to check to see if that was the problem. Then on a NON-PRODUCTION SERVER give 777 access to the entire rails directory.

Comment: if i'm understanding you right, you're suggesting I `chmod 777 myapp` where `myapp` is the root directory of my rails application? If that's the case, I've just done this locally and I'm still getting the same issue. Though I'm not sure what you mean by `This is generally the result of some directory in your Rails directory.` Are you saying I should `chmod 777` all directories in my rails root dir?

Comment: and, now that I try it - that's exactly right. I did a `chmod 777 *` in the rails root dir. voila.

Comment: Edited. I got sidetracked mid-sentence. chmod 777 recursively.